# Layershifting near windows

Tags: creality-ender-3, layer-shifting

I just got my Ender 3 V2 a few days ago. I have started designing a simple local church but the surface of the print is not what I was expecting.

The main issue is layers not being exactly on top of each other near openings(windows). (Red circles in the attached image). Is this setting related or do I need to change my model?

For the blue circle, it is not a nice and flat surface. It happens in this location in every print of the church. You can see it in the background as well.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to improve these issues?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix it or what could cause it? Do I need to change some settings?

Comment: I have impression that it is over-extruded (looking at bottom layer, doorway, and wall below the balcony, the stairway). Do you have belts reasonably tensioned? What if you lower the flow (even underextrude a tiny bit) and raise temperature (try to convert retraction/pressure issue even to a leaking issue)? Try these and edit above answer - we may evolve it to become a real answer. You may try to use [chat] for consultations.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP. StackExchange is a Q&A site *not* a forum of threaded messages. The answer section is not for a back and forth chat, that is why there is a comment section and chatrooms... You can address someone under your question in the comments by preceding their name with the `@` symbol. I've deleted this answer and moved it to the comments under the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's a **retraction** issue, not layer shift.

Your nozzle *starts* printing a new line in those areas but doesn't extrude enough plastic at the first moments, resulting in a weak line.